# Problem with the task. Write a program that determines and prints those numbers that are divisible by 3 among the entered numbers

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the task. Firstly here are some guidelines for the task.
Input of program: A natural number is loaded from the standard input first n and then n natural numbers each in a new line.
Output of program:All loaded numbers divisible by 3 are printed in order on the standard output.
Print each number in a separate line.
Example I entered the numbers:

```
100    
99    
3    
4    
6
```

Each number must be in new line.

When I press enter the program must show me which numbers are divisible by 3. Example:

```
99    
3    
6
```

Here is my code

```
string a;
int n;
while (true)
{
    a = Console.ReadLine();
    if (a == string.Empty)
        break;

    n = Convert.ToInt32(a);
    {
        if (n % 3 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I enter a number that is divisible by 3 the program prints it immediately instead of waiting for me to finish entering numbers and only then to print numbers that are divisible by 3.

Comment: Add all numbers into a list. When you input a non-number, process the list and print the ones % 3 == 0.

Comment: Build a string with the dividable numbers and a newline, print out the string when the program ends?

Comment: Sidenote: `if (a == string.Empty)` - better check this with `string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)` or `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(a)`

Comment: Also note: _"A natural number is loaded from the standard input **first n** and then n natural numbers"_ - you didn't implement the bold part.

Comment: Ok, since this is obviously coursework: Are you allowed to use `List`? Are you familiar with Arrays, for example `int[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restucture your program to first take all inputs and then process them.

You can do it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // storage for all numbers
        var numbers = new List<int>();

        while (true)
        {
            var a = Console.ReadLine();
            if (a == string.Empty)
                break;

            // error handling to avoid crashing if non integers are given
            try
            {
                // adding all numbers in case you want to do other things with them 
                numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(a));
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Not a number: {a}");
            }
        }

        // process the collected numbers
        foreach (var n in numbers)
        {
            if (n % 3 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Testrun:

```
2
5
6
99
Apple
Not a number: Apple
102

6
99
102
```

---

As suggested in the comments: this will not fullfill the task given, you would need to read one number, then read as many inputs (so no `while true: ...` ).

Answer (score 3):

Show bellow maybe you can find something usefull:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var output = string.Empty;

        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int iterations))
        {
            while (iterations-- > 0) // or iterations > 0 and if number pass then increase the iterations
            {
                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int number) /*&& number != 0*/ && number % 3 == 0)
                {
                    output += $"{Environment.NewLine}{number}";
                    // iterations--;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
```

for the people they say string should not be added:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder(Environment.NewLine);

        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int iterations))
        {
            while (iterations-- > 0) // or iterations > 0 and if number pass then increase the iterations
            {
                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int number) /*&& number != 0*/ && number % 3 == 0)
                {
                    output.AppendLine($"{Environment.NewLine}{number}");
                    //iterations--;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
```

and solution with list:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int iterations))
        {
            //var output = new List<int>();
            var length = iterations;
            var output = new int[length];

            while (iterations > 0) // or iterations > 0 and if number pass then increase the iterations
            {
                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int number) /*&& number != 0*/ && number % 3 == 0)
                {
                    //outpu.Add(number);
                    output[length - iterations] = number;
                    iterations--;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, output));
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the "inner" parse fails, it still decreases `iterations` ... not necessarily wrong. Requirements don't say anything about that. Just for consideration ...

Comment: _"string should not be added"_ - good point. I've been told that's an outdated "optimization" and doesn't really matter _today_. I must admit that I haven't dug into this for some time and use concat until someone can prove to me it's an issue.

Comment: Sure, for small amount  of strings no mether how at all for learning porpouses.